# Using batch file to fetch src value of script tag

Tags: batch-file

I am using this script for fetch the src value.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[] " %%a in('find "src=" ^< "test2.html" ')do echo "%%a"
```

the output is coming like this: src="homepage/explore/color_factory.js">

But I want like this: homepage/app.js from this

**test2.html :**

```
<script src="homepage/app.js"></script>
<script src="homepage/color_factory.js"></script> 
<script src="homepage/config.js"></script>
```

Comment: would a delimiter `"` help?

Comment: If suppose i am using delimiter " even i am not getting anything.

Comment: without seeing what the relevant HTML line(s) are, we are relying on intuition. Where does `app.js` come from? (btw - your posted code will not work as it requires a space before the `do`. Please post **actual** code.

Comment: Like @Magoo said without a snippet of your HTML file, its not possible to give you an answer. I can't anderstand the `[]`delimiters in an html file, and you don't need the `<`to get a value from a file with `find`.

Comment: test2.html  :  <script src="homepage/app.js"></script>
 <script src="homepage/color_factory.js"></script>
 <script src="homepage/config.js"></script>

Comment: @SachaDee, you could state `find "src=" "test2.html"`, but then you'll get a header containing the file name in the output of `find`; input redirection `<` avoids that; you could also use a pipe like `type "test2.html" | find "src="`, but this is worse in terms of performance with respect to `<` (a pipe initiates new `cmd` instances for either side)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==^>" %%a in ('type test.html ^| find "src="') do echo %%~a
```

Comment: Thank u its working.but coming like dis "homepage/app.js".please give solution for Removing(") also.thanks advance

Comment: output is printing multiple times.i am using edited answer also

Comment: put `@echo off` at start of your script, check my edit again

Comment: already @echo off start of my script is there.but printing multiple time in my output

Comment: It work perfectly with the html snippet you passed !

Comment: Don't anderstand, put an example of the inpu and desired output

Comment: no, there is no comma in html file.i am only putting comma for every line of my output using this code echo './public/min-safe/%%~a', . but i dont want comma(for last line only) .do u got my point

Comment: do you output that in a file ?

Comment: If you want to delete only the last `,` you have to know how much line will be found. You can do that only if you first output in a file or a list  and then count how much element was found and delete the last element's last char

Comment: Irrespective line count is it not possible to delete last line of comma?

Comment: You first have to save in a file or in alist all founded element and the you can do that